# How to assign array value to another input type using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery can you help me. How to assign array input to assign another input value using jquery?

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Date</label><input type="date" name="PostingDate[]" id="date" style="text-align: center;"class="form-control " required /></td>
    <input type="date" style="display: none;" name="AddedOn" class="KR" />
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date=$("#date").val();
    $(".KR").val(date);
</script>
```

want to assign the date to this input field.

Comment: Is their anyone know about this help me..

Comment: You are already assigning, now what help required?

Comment: Yes, i tried to print it shows nothing

Comment: How it will show, you keep it hidden already

Comment: Is it correct to allocate an array value to input box

Comment: Yes unless jquery library is not loaded

Comment: Using php i echo the value it display nothing

Comment: how you echo it? show some code

Comment: $empid=$_SESSION['eid'];
echo ($_POST["AddedOn"]);
echo ( $_POST["TimeIn"]); 
 $query1 = "INSERT INTO tblbreak
  (emp_id, AddedOn) 
  VALUES (:empid, :AddedOn)";
//echo $query1;
  $statement1 = $connect->prepare($query1);
  $statement1->execute(
   array(
     ':empid'  => $empid, 
     ':AddedOn' =>$_POST["AddedOn"], 
     
   )
  );

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL. I edited the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
    $('#date').on("change",function(){
         $(".KR").val($(this).val());
         $(".KR").show()
    })
```

Comment: If delete the code(   $(".KR").show() ) it not inserted.